# Selecting right tools for iphone app dev

Tags: iphone

I have been surfing the web to find the best to develop small iphone app on WINDOWS XP SP3.

Question :- Is it possible to develop a simple iphone application, that connects to MSSQL database gets the data and displays in iphone app.

Can anybody please suggest the right tools to select..

Thanks a lot for suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

You need a Mac for serious App-Development.

The only other way I see is to write an iPhone-optimized web-application, that should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to do any iPhone development on that Windows machine, as you need Xcode to start developing projects. This only runs on Mac OS.

For a good discussion of iPhone development requirements, try [this article](http://idev4iphone.blogspot.com/2009/03/6-tools-for-beginning-iphone.html): only the first three are really necessary, of course.